# Posting Pdf from facebook and twitter activity controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a code that converts my `UIView` to pdf. Now I want to be able to use this PDF in the `UIActivityController` for Facebook and Twitter integration. I don't know how to go about it, but the code for the PDF is displayed below:

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

How do I initialize the PDF for posting in Facebook and Twitter and even email?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can’t upload pdf to Facebook and Twitter. It’s probably going to be best if you have an FTP server to upload it to..

You can mail and print it, check this

```
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @ "data" ofType: @ "pdf"]];
    UIActivityViewController *act=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:act animated:YES completion:nil];
```